# jquery toggel in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, toggle

my code

```
<li id="dropdownToggle"> Points
         <ul  class="menudropdown">
              <li> Assign Points</li>
               <li>Points Issues</li>
          </ul>
  </li>
```

CSS

```
.menudropdown {
    display:none;
}
```

JS template helper

```
'click #dropdownToggle':function(event){
    $(event.currentTarget).next('.menudropdown').toggle();
}
```

Looks like the problem is with js code, what is the issue here?

Comment: change `next` to `find` or `children` `next` will select your next element just after 'dropdownToggle' li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
    $(event.currentTarget).find('.menudropdown').toggle();
```

This is the JSFiddle: [**CLICK HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehmduy2w/)